# Joomla login case insensitive?

Tags: authentication, joomla1.5

Is there a way to modify the Joomla 1.5 login to make it case insensitive? I could not find anything in the Joomla forum.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. I misread your question the first time. New answer -

The user name is not case sensitive so you don't have to change anything there. The password is case sensitive, but you would have to actually convert the input to all caps or all lowercase before Joomla compares the input to the stored password because all passwords are hashed. That means that any difference in any character would result in a different hash. It would also be a really bad idea to do that.

Comment: Which files in the com_user component do I have to modify? The website will be used for a very short period of time, so I am not worried about updates. Thanks....

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was thinking along the same lines. Because I am assigning the passwords, I converted all passwords to lowercase, and then modified the login script to convert the password input to lowercase. So far it works fine.